# AWS Cognito SMS delivery Issue with iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

We are facing some **technical issues with sms service in iOS AWS Cognito login**. I signed up with my account details in AWS Cognito and I got below O/P,

```
 Response body:
{"CodeDeliveryDetails":{"AttributeName":"phone_number","DeliveryMedium":"SMS","Destination":"+********8888"}}
```

But still **am not received any sms from aws**. This happened only today, but yesterday it works fine. Is there anything I have to set in my AWS account settings. Anybody knows what is the exact limit for sms.  I refer some tutorials, and they ask me to request amazon customer service in order to extend the limit. Anyone have any idea about this? what is the correct procedure to handle this? If you know about anything, It would be helpful for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cognito Identity uses AWS SNS to dispatch SMS to your users. The pricing of the SMS dispatch can be found in [AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/sms-pricing/).

You can monitor your SMS deliveries by subscribing to daily usage reports from Amazon SNS. Each day that you send at least one SMS message, Amazon SNS will deliver a usage report as a CSV file to an Amazon S3 bucket that you specify. You'll find details on the setup in [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_usage.html#daily_usage_subscribe).

If you can't find relevant hints to solve your issue in those reports, you should contact AWS support directly from your AWS console.

Regards,